# Android - Change Spinner Popup Dialog Color Programatically

Tags: android, kotlin, dialog, spinner

I have a Spinner object that looks like this:

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/createsub_category_spinner"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:spinnerMode="dialog" />
```

and a spinner_item.xml:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:gravity="end"
    android:padding="5dip"
    android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="18sp" />
```

and then in the code:

```
categorySpinner = find(R.id.createsub_category_spinner)
        val categoryAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.categories, R.layout.spinner_item)
        categorySpinner.adapter = categoryAdapter
        categorySpinner.setPopupBackgroundResource(sub.color)
        categorySpinner.setSelection(sub.category)
```

where I expect that the setPopupBackgroundResource(sub.color) modifies the dialog's default white background. But this does not happen? What am I missing?

After some further testing I noticed that the code shown above work if I have `android:spinnerMode="dropdown"`, somehow the same doesnt apply when the dialog mode is selected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html#setPopupBackgroundResource(int)):

`Set the background drawable for the spinner's popup window of choices. Only valid in MODE_DROPDOWN; this method is a no-op in other modes.`

So unfortunately this won't work in dialog mode.

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
spinner.setPopupBackgroundResource(R.drawable.spinner_background);
```

and here the spinner_background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<solid android:color="#ffffff" />
</shape>
```

Comment: Thanks but this way I cannot set the color dinamically, I need a way to do this pogrammatically, so that the color changes based on the `sub.color` value

Comment: how many color have you got programmatically? you can create one drawable background for each color...

Comment: That wouldn't be optimal at all, we are talking, and the number it's going to increase, of about 40 colors.

Comment: did you try spinner.setBackgroundColor() ??

Comment: yes, it changes the spinner background color, not the popup dialog background color

Comment: ok you have change the background of the items in the spinner, you have to change the item colour with item.setBackgroundColor(); for each item in the spinner list

Comment: changing the item background would change both, the spinner background and would change only partially the popup dialog background color, leaving the edges white

Comment: for the edge white you have to play with match parent attribute of the item layout... the spinner background is decided by the first item, so leave the color white for the first item in the list.. you have to play with the items position

Comment: This is kind of a botched approach which would work for example when I select another spinner element I would get the spinner background wrong. There has to be a better way, Thanks for the help and the time invested though

Comment: when you select an item just change the background color of the item selected